# How to retrieve Facebook likes with descriptions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, set, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

How can I get list of facebook likes (pages that user has liked ) with descriptions

Im using `/me/likes` object, but it won't give me likes descriptions. I understand I can use FQL with **"WHERE page_id in (LIST_OF_IDS)"** - or request for every like separately

Is there any way to get it with one request ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done via FQL with the following query:

> SELECT name, description FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id
>   FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me())

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20name%2C%20description%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_fan%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme())%0A

Answer (score 1):

Or this way using the **Graph API**: `USER_ID?fields=likes.fields(description)`

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible with the Graph API, don´t take FQL. The Graph API is usually faster and easier:

```
me/likes?fields=id,name,description
```

Result (from my account):

```
"data": [
{
  "id": "244993732224805",
  "name": "Jón Gnarr",
  "created_time": "2012-12-06T00:35:43+0000"
},
{
  "id": "161086703983",
  "name": "Design Shack",
  "description": "We only offer the cream of great design, filtering through lots of the redesigns that occur every day across the Internet, and cataloguing the greatest projects out there - perfect for getting that spark of creativity going again.\n\t\nRegular articles will teach you new techniques for creating your own designs, and daily community news ensures that you're up to date with the latest developments elsewhere.\n\t\nIf you want to be updated every time a new design or tutorial is added, you can subscribe:\n\t\nDesign Shack RSS Feed\nhttp://feeds.feedburner.com/designshack\n\nTwitter\nhttp://twitter.com/designshack",
  "created_time": "2012-12-04T14:40:08+0000"
},
{
  "id": "274797542535942",
  "name": "Chasing Aurora",
  "description": "Chasing Aurora is an explorative 2D aerial action game about the dream of flight.\n\nDrop from the cliff and ride the wind from peak to peak. Fight for the beacon of light with up to three friends in the hostile environment of the Alps.",
  "created_time": "2012-12-04T12:07:13+0000"
}, 
...
```